# migrate dataType and paramType got Springdoc

Tags: springfox, springdoc

I have this SpringFox api description param:

```
@ApiImplicitParam(value = "token", required = true, dataType = "string",
      paramType = "header")
```

I migrated it to SpringDoc using:

```
@Parameter(value = "token", required = true, dataType = "string",
      paramType = "header")
```

I can't find how to replace  `dataType` and `paramType`. Do you know what should be the proper way to migrate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paramType` uses `in`.
`dataType` uses `schema`.

example

```java
  @GetMapping
  public String index(@Parameter(name = "token", required = true, in = ParameterIn.HEADER, schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class)) @RequestHeader("token") String header) {
    return header;
  }
```

If RequestHeader annotation is attached, it can be simplified a little more.

```java
  @GetMapping
  public String index(@Parameter(name = "token", required = true) @RequestHeader("token") String header) {
    return header;
  }
```

[image]